# What is the easiest and cheapest way to sell a download on my website?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, e-commerce, paypal

I know that there are several e-commerce plugins, like JigoShop, WP E Commerce, and Woo Commerce.

I also know there area lot of payment gateways like authorize.net and Paypal.

However, if I have a really simple piece of software that I want to sell on my website, a single file download, what is the easiest and cheapest way to accomplish this? Can I use one of the WP plugins without having to pay for PayFlow Pro to allow the download?

Comment: if you downvote please explain why. seems like this is a valid question.

Comment: I'm not a down-voter, but your question is geared to choosing a payment gateway, not choosing a WP plugin. It seems like you've already searched out the plugins that are compatible. WPSE is not a place to determine payment gateways.

Comment: @BrianFegter Me is not only a down voter - a close voter on this one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for Woocommerce! In my opinion the best and most powerful free ecommerce plugin.
They offer also features for download products

Answer (score 2):

[Easy Digital Downloads](http://easydigitaldownloads.com) is in my opinioin the best plugin if you are selling downloads. You can see a full review of the plugin [here](http://wpnuggets.com/wp-plugin-review/easy-digital-downloads/).

Answer (score 0):

It does not get any more simple than Google checkout's buy now button where you have the built in option to sell a digital good. After choosing "Digital Good" you'll have options to enter the product's download link and key. Next you'll press generate code and just paste the  code anywhere on your site.

Comment: Google Checkout is not available in most of the countries ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this plugin to process digital downloads for sale (not yet sold anything but tested it out myself) and not had any problems - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paid-downloads/

(p.s. I assume it's ok to add an answer to an old question like this? I am new here)